# Properly using map[string]interface{}?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I have two related questions, I did not want to open a new thread for both questions:

Given the following code:

```
1    type Request struct {
2       Values map[string]interface{}
3    }
4
5    func (r Request) Send() {
6       client := &http.Client{}
7       resp, _ := http.Post("http://example.com", "text/json", &r.Values)
8    }
```

The idea is to be able to send a block of an unknown amount `key => value`, `key => key => value`, etc. to our API endpoint.

**Question 1:**

How do I assign to `Request.Values`? An example use case we may need to employ is the following (Excuse the PHP Code, we're transitioning):

```
'name' => [ $first, $last ],
'address' => [ 'city' => 'city', 'state' => 'state' ],
'country' => 'US'
```

In this example we have `key => value`, `key => [ values ]`, and `key => [ key => value ]`

How can I take that and assign the exact same values to `Request.Values`?

**Question 2:**

Obviously `Values` is of type `map[string]interface{}` , how can I convert that to type `io.Reader` so I can send the values to the server?

Any guidance is greatly appreciated on both questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Question 1

You can assign values to `Request.Values` just like with any other value.

Example ([on play](http://play.golang.org/p/rFh0N3vmrW)):

```
x := map[string]interface{}{
    "foo": []string{"a","b"},
    "bar": "foo",
    "baz": 10.4,
}
```

#### Question 2

You are in need of an intermediate format, for example [JSON](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json).

With this package you can marshal your `Request` struct to a JSON string, transfer
said string and parse it on the other (PHP?) side.